# How do you change background of specific cell in a JQuery.DataTable?

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I'm trying to change the styling of some specific cells in a DattaTable, but I'm not sure how to do that. I know how to change for an entire column, but that's not what i need.
So let's say that my data is like:

```
{
name: "user1",
gender : "f",
age: 54
},{
name: "user1",
gender : "m",
age: 33
}
```

In my table, I have

```
columns: [{ 
data: "name"
},{
data: "age"
}]
```

And I want to highlight, lets say, the age cells in blue case gender = "m" or red case gender = "f".

Any suggestion on how I can accomplish that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use the [column configuration's `createdCell` function](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell).

Basically, you need to add a column definition for the gender column that includes a callback that will be called when the cell is populated.  Try adding this object to your columns array:

```
    {
      data: "gender",
      createdCell: function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
        var color = (cellData === 'm') ? 'blue' : 'red';
        $(td).css('color', color);
      }
    }
```

[Here is a working example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/l5fA5vybgyr5MWFdf6UO?p=preview)

Comment: I actually meant to change the style of the age cell (or any other cell) based on the gender cell. But this works too! It's perfect! Thank you!!

Comment: Same as above, but use 'background-color', instead of 'color' when you change the CSS.

Comment: This is far better than other answers to this same question that used the render callback and css nth-child selectors to target td cells! Of course createdCell is only available since DataTables version 1.10.